# Tesseract self fails and closes

Tags: c#, tesseract

After running for 1 hour, my picture solving application using Teserract crashes:

> **System.AccessViolationException:** 'An attempt to read or write protected memory. This is usually an indication that the other memory is corrupt.'

```cs
try
{
    IWebElement ttID = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("div#root div.captcha__container > img"));
              
    pictureBox1.ImageLocation = ttID.GetAttribute("src");
    Thread.Sleep(2000);

    var img = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image);
    var ocr = new TesseractEngine("./tessdata", "eng");
    var result = ocr.Process(img);
    richTextBox1.Text = result.GetText();
    if (infoCheckBox.Checked == true)
    {
        next();
    }
}
catch
{
    kod();
}
```

Comment: System.AccessViolationException: 'An attempt to read or write protected memory. This is usually an indication that the other memory is corrupt. '

Comment: Please run your program and watch meory usage over time. Does it go up?

Comment: @SinaHoseinkhani yes, the use of memory is constantly increasing.

Comment: can you send more code, to investigate if it is indeed this part of program with memory leak?

Comment: @SinaHoseinkhani [link](https://www.codepile.net/pile/GergD2pJ)

Answer (score 0):

My suspition is memoty leak, I hope this helps:

```
try
{
    IWebElement ttID = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("div#rootdiv.captcha__container > img"));
    pictureBox1.ImageLocation = ttID.GetAttribute("src");
    Thread.Sleep(2000);

    using (var img = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image))
    {
        var ocr = new TesseractEngine("./tessdata", "eng");
        var sonuc = ocr.Process(img);
        richTextBox1.Text = sonuc.GetText();
        if (infoCheckBox.Checked == true)
        {
            durum.Text = "otomatik çözme deneniyor...";
            Yandexİleri();
        }
        durum.Text = "otomatik çözme denendi.";
    }
}
catch
{
    baslat_kodlari();
}``
```

Comment: it still closes after a while.